# Json not working with HttpPost

Tags: android, json, entity, http-post

I am using this code to send this to my php file.
The file looks what is coming like this.

```
file_put_contents('dump.txt', "POST: \n" . print_r($_POST, true) . "\n\n\n GET: \n" . print_r($_GET, true));
```

I am sending the json like this:

```
public void postData(String url,JSONObject json) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String object = "?data=" +json.toString();
        System.out.println("object:" + object);

        try {

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url.toString());
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            System.out.println("url:" + url.toString());
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(object); 
            System.out.println("json:" + json.toString());

            se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
            httppost.setEntity(se); 

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            String temp = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            System.out.println("response:" + response);

            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            System.out.println("Statuscode " + statusCode);

            if(statusCode==200)
            {
                    Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this,
                                            "Verstuurd",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            else if(statusCode!=200) {

                            Toast.makeText(this, statusCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

           /* try {
                String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        Toast.makeText(this, responseBody, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        }*/


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }



    }
```

The log files are this:

```
01-08 09:36:00.278: I/System.out(1124): object:?data={"id":"69403","timestamp":"08-01-2013 09:36:00","longitude":"-122.084095","latitude":"37.422005"}
01-08 09:36:00.298: I/System.out(1124): json:{"id":"69403","timestamp":"08-01-2013 09:36:00","longitude":"-122.084095","latitude":"37.422005"}
01-08 09:36:01.038: I/System.out(1124): response:org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@412d1b38
01-08 09:36:01.038: I/System.out(1124): Statuscode 200
```

But i am getting an empty file in dump.txt

```
POST: 
Array
(
)



 GET: 
Array
(
)
```

**EDIT**

Something is wrong with the setEntity(or somewhere around there), because when i already paste ?data= in the url i get this from the PHP file:

```
POST: 
Array
(
)



 GET: 
Array
(
    [data] => 
)
```

Comment: Why isn't your "url:..." printing in your log messages?

Comment: Because i thought of security. it would be something like: "http://server.com/locatie.php"

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String object = "?data=" +URLEncoder.encode(json.toString(), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: No that's still not working. Still not receiving anything. And i know that the code is working. Tested it before